# AWS CLI Show Failed S3 CP or SYNC uploads

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-cli

I'm having an issue with AWS CLI where if I do an `s3 cp` or `s3 sync` with smaller files `(<10GB)` it works fine but when I try same command with files `(>10gb)` it returns an exit status of 1 which means some files failed to copy.

Is there a way to show/list the files that failed to copy/sync?
Note: All copies are between s3 to s3 ( same bucket, same region, same ACL, just different "folders paths")

Answer (score 1):

[Looking at the official docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/s3/cp.html), when work with files more than 10gb you need to specify in CLI commands an argument `--expected-size` or the upload may fail when it reaches the default part limit of 10,000.

Example for a file larger than 50GB:

`aws s3 cp - s3://mybucket/stream.txt --expected-size 54760833024`

I hope that works for you.
Keep rocking!.

Comment: Hey @jonathan-brizio thanks for the comment. Does this apply when copying within the same bucket?

I'm not uploading from local to S3, source and destination is the same s3 bucket at different paths.

Comment: Oh, you're trying to sync between two different bucket names. So try to do this from web console: Just navigate to the files you want to copy, click on "Actions" -> "Copy" then navigate to the destination bucket and "Actions" -> "Paste".

Comment: The `--expected-size` would only be needed when copying from `stdin` (using the `-`).

Answer (score 0):

Faced a different problem that led me to the same question: is there a way to see which uploads failed?

Per [AWS docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/s3/cp.html), you can use the `--only-show-errors` flag to get only failing uploads in the output of the command. Works for both `s3 cp` and `s3 sync`.